# categorizing data in R

Tags: r

Im trying to categorising my data into different group based on type of data. My data and code is as follow:

```
bank    ROE
bank1   0.73
bank2   0.94
bank3   0.62
bank4   0.57
bank5   0.31
bank6   0.53
bank7   0.39
bank8   0.01
bank9   0.16
bank10  0.51
bank11  0.84
bank12  0.18

sob <- c('bank1', 'bank2','bank3',)
fob <- c('bank4','bank5', 'bank6')
jov <- c('bank7', 'bank8','bank9', 'bank10','bank11')

test$type <- ifelse(test$bank == sob, 1, ifelse(test$bank == fob, 2, ifelse(test$bank == jov, 3,     4)))
test
```

However this code doesn't work as category showed up wrongly and I get this warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(test1$bank, jov) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Can anyone show me what I have done wrong and what I should do to get it right?

Thanks

Comment: You should look into the difference between `==` and `%in%` for a start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `%in%`-operator instead of the identity--you are comparing against a vector here.

Like so:

```
test$type <- ifelse(test$bank %in% sob, 1, ifelse(test$bank %in% fob, 2, ifelse(test$bank %in% jov, 3,     4)))

> test
     bank  ROE type
1   bank1 0.73    1
2   bank2 0.94    1
3   bank3 0.62    1
4   bank4 0.57    2
5   bank5 0.31    2
6   bank6 0.53    2
7   bank7 0.39    3
8   bank8 0.01    3
9   bank9 0.16    3
10 bank10 0.51    3
11 bank11 0.84    3
12 bank12 0.18    4
```

Alternatively, to avoid the cumbersome if-else structures you could do the classification resetting levels of a factor.

first copy the bank variable 
test$type<-test$bank

then, re-set the levels, using the vectors defined above (sob, fob, job). Notice the last step, `'other'` is set to the remaining value because bank12 is not defined in the other vectors.

```
levels(test$type) <- list('sob' = sob,
                          'fob' = fob,
                          'jov' = jov,
                          'other' = 'bank12')
```

Resulting in

```
> test
     bank  ROE  type
1   bank1 0.73   sob
2   bank2 0.94   sob
3   bank3 0.62   sob
4   bank4 0.57   fob
5   bank5 0.31   fob
6   bank6 0.53   fob
7   bank7 0.39   jov
8   bank8 0.01   jov
9   bank9 0.16   jov
10 bank10 0.51   jov
11 bank11 0.84   jov
12 bank12 0.18 other
```

Comment: Hi, thank all of you for suggestion, I adjusted the == operator to %in% and it worked perfectly. For suggestion using factor, I just wonder if I had a lot more bank than in this sample, how can I set 'other' to the rest of the data? I'm a newbie in R so please excuse my question if it is too trivial for you guys. Thanks

Comment: You can set the 'other' level to `NA` then assign all with `NA` the level other'. `test$type[is.na(test$type)] <- 'other'`

Comment: This should be the the same as just skipping the fourth line in the list, setting `levels(test$type)=list('sob' = sob, 'fob' = fob,'jov' = jov)`; without explicit assignment of `NA` to `other`. Then any undefined levels will equally be NA. Then @sbebobs test$type[is.na(test$type)] <- 'other' can be used on those.

Comment: Thanks bebop, such as useful suggestion.

Comment: Thanks ako. I will do it

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator in your code compares the vector `test$bank` with the vectors `jov`. As these vectors are of different lengths (12 and 5) and the longer vector is not a multiple of the shorter one such as in the case of `sob` (of length 3), you get a warning message.

To evaluate if a value is equal to any of the values in a vector you can use the `%in%` operator just as @ako suggest. However when working with groups `factor` and `levels` are useful functions. Specify the variable as a factor, then set new levels.

```
test <- data.frame(
  bank = c('bank1','bank2','bank3','bank4','bank5','bank6','bank7','bank8','bank9','bank10','bank11','bank12'),
  ROE = c(0.73,0.94,0.62,0.57,0.31,0.53,0.39,0.01,0.16,0.51,0.84,0.18)
)

test$bank <- factor(test$bank)

levels(test$bank) <- list(
  '1' = c('bank1', 'bank2','bank3'),
  '2' = c('bank4','bank5', 'bank6'),
  '3' = c('bank7', 'bank8','bank9', 'bank10','bank11'),
  'other' = NA
)

test$bank[is.na(test$bank)] <- 'other'
```

Comment: +1. This is what I did [in my `Factor` wrapper](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/7019545) for `factor`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try:

```
lst1 <- list(sob, fob, jov)
test$type <- setNames(rep(seq_along(lst1),sapply(lst1,length)),unlist(lst1))[test$bank]
test$type[is.na(test$type) ] <- 4

test$type
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4
```